# Como obtener la frecuencia de datos en python

Tags: python

.
Hola gente, como va;

Voy a intentar ser directo

1)
Tengo este DaTaframe: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/6k00/data_base_eolica/main/vel_10.csv

Que representa **Velocidad del viento** medido durante **10 años**

2. Necesito convertir esos valores en una frecuencia distribuida, o sea por ejemplo entre 5,01 y 6,00 m/s cuantas veces hubo esa velocidad en ese rango

Y al final formar un DataFrame similar a este:

| Velocidad (rango) | Tiempo (hora |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 252 |
| 2 | 500 |
| 3 | 900 |
| 4 | 1200 |

Y asi hasta un máximo de 30 horas

Muchas gracias por su atención

Comment: `df.groupby('velocidad').count()`

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación. En la función ('velocidad') como puedo determinar los rangos de velocidad? por ejemplo en un DataFrame de 200 mil lineas, existen 500 velocidades entre 2 a 3 m/s

Comment: Puedes filtrar esos datos `df[df["velocidad"]=="2"||df["velocidad"]=="3"]` también podrías usar el método `isin`

Comment: Genial, ahora lo pruebo. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías separar primero los rangos y luego contar por grupos:

```
ranges = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.vel_100, ranges)).count()
```

Comment: una opción bastante válida +1 :D

Comment: Excelente, funcionó a la perfección. También gracias Christian por tus sugestiones

Comment: Como puedo hacer para los resultados salgan dos columnas separadas? [Rango, Horas] porque me salen todo junto [Rango hora]

Comment: @el6k001 eso es otra pregunta